# Is it possible to make multiple assignments using a conditional expression?

Tags: python, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

Here is the example:

```
age = 10
reject = False

if age < 10:
    st = 'Kid'
    reject = True

else:
    st='Adult'
    reject = False
```

Is it possible?  Something like:

```
statement1:statement2 if age < 10 else statement3:statment4
```

I am still having problems with understanding ternary operator in Python.

Comment: The syntax you requested is not possible.  The conditional expression syntax is `true-expression if condition else false-expression`.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy  Well, you can actually bind names with expressions.  `globals().__setitem__('st', 'Kid')`, for example.

Comment: Just use the if-else statement. There is no good reason to try to cram your code into a single line, especially if it requires weird, unidiomatic usage of language constructs not meant to achieve that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
st, reject = ('Kid', True) if age < 10 else ('Adult', False)
```

Comment: is there another possible way???   assuming  that if kid < 20, if less than 20 ONLY assign  "rejected=True" and for adult st="Adult" and Rejected=False

Comment: other than st, reject = (None, True) if age < 20 else ('Adult', False) i can't think of anything off the top of my head

Answer (score 7):

Assignment statements support [multiple targets](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

```
>>> age = 10
>>> st, reject = ('Kid', True) if age < 10 else ('Adult', False)
>>> st, reject
('Adult', False)
```

Comment: is there another possible way??? assuming that if kid < 20, if less than 20 ONLY assign "rejected=True" and for adult assign st="Adult" and Rejected=False

Comment: Technically possible, but ugly.  Just use an if statement and stop trying to be so fancy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
st, reject = ('Kid', True) if age < 10 else ('Adult', False)
```

When you use:

```
var1, var2 = 1, 2
```

You are doing the same as:

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
```

And when you use:

```
var1 = 1 if x == y else 2
```

Your are doing the same as:

```
if x == y:
    var1 = 1
else:
    var1 = 2
```

If you want with this define multiples variables you have to make a tuple `()` with the variables and they will be unpacked.